# String manipulation when one string starts with what the other ends with

Tags: javascript, string

For example:

```
var x = "abc"
var y = "bcd"
```

In this case, `y` starts with what `x` ends with (`"bc"`). I want to strip those contents from y. So I want to end up with `"d"`.

How can I do this?

Comment: This reads like a coding request.  What have you tried to solve this contrived problem yourself?

Comment: you can split x into an array and compare with y.

Comment: Only ends and starts? or just includes

Comment: @PaulThomas Only starts and ends.

Comment: One approach, you could logically start at the end of `x`, slicing off the last character, seeing if y starts with it, if it doesn't, then slice off the end of x - 1 and check again, if it doesn't, repeat until it does.  On the first match, slice off of y the length of the characters from x that it starts with.

Comment: @Taplar Does stackoverflow actually have explicit guidelines that say you have to state what you've tried?

Comment: Reference [ask].  Generally if you ask how to do something, and show no effort, then yes.  People are going to ask you to show your effort.

Comment: @Taplar Yeah I referenced it, I can't find anything saying that I have to show what I've tried. I don't see the point in doing so. Stackoverflow is a database of questions and answers. What I've personally tried is irrelevant.

Comment: "In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, **and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself**. The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible."  You have not stated what problem you have solving this yourself.  You've simply asking for an answer.  This means it's a coding request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will determine the intersect.
NOTE: It will also short circuit if a non match occurs.

```js
var x = "abc";
var y = "bcd";
var z = "";

for (let i = x.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  let sample = x.substring(i);
  console.log(sample);
  if (y.startsWith(sample)) {
    z = sample
  } else if (y.includes(sample) == false) {
    i = 0;
  }
}

// Log out the intesect
console.log(z);

//remove it from y
y = y.substring(z.length);

console.log(x+y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just start at the beginning (or end) of x until you find a substring that y starts with:

```js
var x = "abchjkjhdfl"
var y = "dflbcd"

let start = 0
while (start < x.length && !y.startsWith(x.slice(start))){
    start++
}
// remove "dfl"
console.log(y.slice(x.length - start))
```